Continuity of a function in Ham-Sandwich theorem (case n = 3)
So I came here to try to undestand the Harald Hanche-Olsen's explanation in question from Proof of the Ham-Sandwich theorem.
Basically, the question is how can I prove the continuity of the function $g$ from https://planetmath.org/proofofhamsandwichtheorem.
Harald use some arguments about essential support, which I'm trying to convince myself, but the point is that he said since the values of $t_{-}^{+}(p)$ is characterized by $H(p,t)$ just touching either of these sets and then the continuity of $t_{-}^{+}$ is estabilished.
So, how is the smart way to prove this? By sequences? $\varepsilon$-$\delta$'s? Please, someone help me with this. Otherwise, if someone has another idea to prove the continuity of $g$, it would help a lot.
